# What songs from Final Fantasy 13 are used in the sequel?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2, final-fantasy-13

On Final Fantasy XIII-2's OST, I have noticed that some songs that were used in the game aren't present, most likely because they were songs that were originally from Final Fantasy XIII. As I do not own the first game's OST, I would love to know the names of all the songs that were re-used.

Comment: I don't think any of tracks are the same. They've never released absolutely every track I don't think.

Comment: @danRhul There are several tracks that were borrowed from the first game. One example is the track "Vile Peaks" from FF13, which was used in Archylte Steppe in the second game. I'm just trying to get a comprehensive list for reference.

Comment: Ah I wasn't aware. You can find the two lists online. Its just trawling through 4CDs worth of tracks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the collector's edition of *Final Fantasy XIII-2* which came with the OST, and I went out and bought the *Final Fantasy XIII* OST to compare the two. In terms of a strict comparison between the OSTs, there is no overlap. Instead, several character rearrangements—usually adding lyrics—were created specifically for *Final Fantasy XIII-2*:

- "Final Fantasy XIII-2 -Overture-" (from "Final Fantasy XIII -The Promise-")<sup>1</sup>
- "Final Fantasy XIII-2 -The Future-" (from "Final Fantasy XIII -The Promise-")
- "Serah's Theme -Memories-" (From "Serah's Theme")
- "Blessed Fanfare" (from "Glory's Fanfare")

As well as:

> "Hope's Theme -Tomorrow's Dream-" (from "Hope's Theme")

Not to mention the usual rearrangements of the Chocobo Theme:

- "Groovy Chocobo"
- "Chocobo Rodeo"
- "Crazy Chocobo"

I couldn't find any definitive "these are the tracks we borrowed from *Final Fantasy XIII*" list, but—based on what I've heard in game—there are a number of tracks borrowed from the *Final Fantasy XIII* that don't appear on the *Final Fantasy XIII-2* OST but appear in game<sup>2</sup>. This list is based on my ear, so it might not be exhaustive or 100% accurate:

#### Disc 1

- "Defilers of Fate"
- "Saber's Edge"
- "The Hanging Ledge"
- "The Warpath Home"
- "The Vestage"
- "Promised Eternity"
- "Lake Bresha"

As well as:

> "Snow's Theme"

#### Disc 2

- "Blinded by Light"
- "Battle Results"
- "The Vile Peaks"
- "March of the Dreadnoughts"
- "The Gapra Whitewood"
- "Forever Fugitives"
- "The Sunleth Waterscape"

As well as:

> "Sazh's Theme" (DLC only)

#### Disc 3

- "Can't Catch a Break" (DLC only, I think)
- "Atonement"
- "Nautilus"
- "Feast of Betrayal"
- "Test of the l'Cie"
- "Separate Paths"
- "Desperate Struggle"
- "Choose to Fight"

#### Disc 4

- "The Archlyte Steppe"
- "Sulyya Springs"
- "Taejin's Tower"
- "Dust to Dust"
- "Start Your Engines"

---

#### Notes

<sup>Note 1</sup>: The main theme from *Final Fantasy XIII* is still the main theme in *Final Fantasy XIII-2*, so like the former, many of the tracks in the latter are arrangements of the core theme.

<sup>Note 2</sup>: I left tracks that were borrowed out of context inline, but hid tracks that appear in context and might spoil a plot point using the spoiler markdown.